# why gfortran under cygwin can't compile correctly?

Tags: cygwin, gfortran

I installed cygwin under windows and gfortran packages.

Then I write a simple f90 file

```
program test
implicit none
write(*,*) "hello world"
end program test
```

the file was named test.f90

then I open cygwin terminal and write

```
gfortran -o test.exe test.f90
```

everything seems ok, there are no errors, and a test.exe is generated.

but

```
./test.exe
```

didn't output anything. What is wrong?

The test.exe is shared [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4WA9GK6t9DMWVnakNfRWxtLXc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: WFM.  Do you have `libgfortran3` installed, and did you run `./test.exe` from within a Cygwin shell (e.g. `bash`) or from within a `cmd` window?

Comment: I have installed libgfortran3 and run ./test.exe within a cygwin shell. Anyway, since it is a exe, it should be working within a cmd window, right?

Comment: It doesn't look like to me that test.exe has been linked against any Cygwin dll's. Do you have other versions of gfortran installed on your machine?