# "Hello world" Fortran (gfortran) fails to run in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, fortran, gfortran

I have the following code:

```
PROGRAM TEST
  IMPLICIT NONE

  PRINT *, "test"
END PROGRAM TEST
```

It is compiled successfully using this command:

```
C:/cygwin64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran.exe test.f08 -o test.exe
```

When I run the program by double clicking it, it produces the error:

"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application."

The file libgfortran-3.dll is in the same folder as the executable. My environment is Windows 8.1 64-bit. Cygwin (Setup.exe version 2.850 (64 bit)) is installed to C:\cyginw64. All defaults packages were installed, along with all "Base" and "Devel" packages. My system PATH environment variable includes C:\cygwin64\bin. Running the program from the Cygwin64 terminal produces no output.

What is causing this error? I have another, more complicated program that suffers from the same error.

Possibly related: [why gfortran under cygwin can't compile correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171345/why-gfortran-under-cygwin-cant-compile-correctly)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What makes you think so? Is it the error message? What could I be missing with all those packages installed? I also found out that I can compile the test program successfully from the Cygwin terminal.

Answer (score 1):

That error code is an `NTSTATUS` code, specifically `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`. Almost without fail that means you are trying to load a 32 bit module into a 64 bit process. Or vice versa. Use a dependency analysis tool to work out which module has the wrong bitness. For example Dependency Walker.